# Shift-F10, prevent context-menu in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, contextmenu, preventdefault, stoppropagation

In my application I have a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> keyboard handler like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 121 && e.shiftKey === true) {
    console.log('shift-f10 detected');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, in recent versions of Firefox (at least FF56), a context-menu is appearing in the top-right of the page:

[image: context-menu appears when user presses shift-10]

I've been unsuccessful in disabling the context-menu with:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Is there a way to prevent this context-menu from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next code:

```
 $document.on('contextmenu',  (ev) => {
        return false;
 });
```

or:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 121 && e.shiftKey === true) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Maybe you can use :

```
 document.body.addEventListener('keydown',function(ev){
      if (ev.keyCode === 121 && ev.shiftKey === true)
               {
                 ev.preventDefault();
               }
    });
```

If this code don't work -  focus don't locate in browser, or  you have other errors.  Try it code.

Comment: Maybe focus in your  didn`t   located in your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded my Firefox installation and now the first snippet you posted seems to be working.